# undo continually vi

Tags: linux, unix, text-editor, vi

I am using vi(not Vim) and I would like to continually undo the changes made. `u` works for a single command undo and `U`for a single line undo. But Is there a way to undo continuously like vim(I recall a command in vim can even undo changes by time!) in vi?
Thanks in Advance.

Edit:
I am using vi version 3.10

Comment: Tell us what vi you're using, there are many. Type: :version and show us what it says.

Comment: Shouldn't this be put on Superuser instead of SO?

Comment: @simendsjo I think vi is most often used for programming related purposes although others can also use it! ;)

Comment: wowrt: can you provide the source of the version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Repeat the undo, with the `.` key.

Comment: But '.' only 'repeats' a single undo in vi.

Comment: I used to be able to do: `u.....` to do 6 undos... But in vim that changed to `uuuuuu`, and the dots would reapply a change that I'd just undone.

Comment: Ah - version 3... I was thinking of about 17 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

*May not work in 3.1 version.*

Undo continually things like stack-popping

```
u . . .
```

Suppose you write `hello` in insert -mode. Go to normal mode, write `hallo` and go to normal mode. Then type `u .`, you get `hello`. Type again `.` and you will get blank. You can reverse it by typing again `u . .` so you will get `hello hallo`. It is very easy to memorize because it works like stacks! I.e. `undo` `repeat the last command` `repeat the last command` where the repeat the last command can be `undo`. When you press `u u`, it does mean `undo the last command`: `undo last command` and the second `u` means `undo the last command and in this case it is u`.

*Tested with `Nvi Version 1.79 (10/23/96) The CSRG, University of California, Berkeley`, OpenBSD. You can get the source [here](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/vi/vi/).*